# excel replace from vba without macros

Tags: excel, excel-formula

this is more out of interest - but I just saw some code in excel which was like replace(replace(replace....

we have a situation where we want to shorten name strins, get rid of titles, turn "superanuation fund" into "s/f".... but there might be a hundred or so options.  I know I could just expose a vba function like:

```
 =replace_from_table( a5, c1:d100)
```

but I'm wondering if it's possible to do in formulas, *without* a hundred nested replaces?

Comment: What data do you have, what are you trying to accomplish with the data?

Comment: I have about 500000 rows of customer data - where the name field is too long to send to a third party.  I want to eventually truncate the name field, but first make intelligent shortenings - for instance getting rid of mr, mrs, master, turning and to &, using abbreviations for common tems, etc etc - ie just apply about 100 common transformations.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?